# Redirect to URL based on one form field

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to create a very simple form which has one field where you can enter a 5 digit number - e.g. 12345. When you submit the form, I'd like the page to redirect to http://www.website.com/12345

I'm sure it must be fairly simple, but I've not been able to find the answer anywhere!

Very grateful for any help.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Can you use a server side language like PHP or ASP? This is easy to do in Javascript but it won't work if it's turned off. Can you live with that?

Comment: Do you have to do this in javascript? What about PHP?

Comment: Did you try `document.location = "http://www.website.com/" + yourTextBox.value;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things that could be prettier than this (such as extracting it to a function of its own, say) but this is in essence what you want to do.

```
<form onSubmit=" location.href = 'http://www.website.com/' + document.getElementById('idOfTheTextField').value; return false; ">
```

Comment: That's brilliant David. Thanks a lot - that was exactly what I wanted and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If people have JavaScript turned off then this wont work, so really you want something like this:

In PHP -

```
<?php 

$number=$_GET['number'];

header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/$number");

?>
```

And your input field should look something like this with 'number' as the name:

```
<input name="number" value=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - it's for an intranet so Javascript won't be an issue.